# Powershell Clear homeDirectory Attribute

Tags: powershell

```
Get-AdUser -Identity $user_id_arr | Set-AdUser -replace @(homeDirectory="")
```

Doesn't work.

```
Get-AdUser -Identity $user_id_arr | Set-AdUser -homeDirectory ""
```

Doesn't work either.

How does one clear an attribute in powershell via cmdlets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set it to $null

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user_id_arr | Set-ADUser -HomeDirectory $null
```

To view the value of HomeDirectory:

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user_id_arr -Properties HomeDirectory
```

Comment: Thank you! Knew it was something easy.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry about this desecration of a grave, but I think I've found a solution for this.

```
Get-ADUser -Identity $user_id_arr | Set-ADUser -Clear HomeDirectory
```

Regards Inter

Answer (score 0):

I use this in production. This will grab all users from an OU and clear the Home folder. (Sets to default)

Get-ADUser -searchbase OU=test,DC=yourcompany,DC=COM" -LDAPFilter "(sAMAccountname=*)" -Properties homeDirectory | % { Set-AdUser -Identity $_.sAMAccountName -Clear homeDirectory }